# How can a cell's background color be set other than the obvious Cell shading property?

Tags: excel

I can't for the life of me figure out why certain cells are shaded in a spreadsheet template I downloaded.  I confirmed that the cell's shading property is set to no color.  The cell has a simple formula: =SUM(J8:K8).
If the background color is being set by code in another cell, I'm not sure how to find it. Searching for the cell name (ex: B7) doesn't come up with anything.  Any suggestions what could be setting the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Conditional Formating options?

It could be that there's a background colour set in there.

In Office 2007 it's on the Ribbon in the Styles section on the Home tab - your best bet is to go for the "Manage Rules..." option, and then check the rules for each worksheet.

Comment: Your rock Zhaph. That was it!  Thanks.